# Multiple API calls based on page size in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, mergemap

API call - `getList()` => returns 1000 numbers

- Say 1,2,3...1000

Make 20 API calls by taking above top 20 results

I am trying to do something like this

```js
this.http.get('urlService').mergeMap((ids: number[]) => this.getItems(ids.slice(0, 20))).
  subscribe(newsList => {
    this.dataRecieved.next(newsList);
  })
```

But its not working somehow

Comment: Could you please say what is the signature of the function `getItems(id)`. Does it expect an array of numbers or a single number as argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) function to combine multiple HTTP requests. It'll emit only when all the observables complete.

```js
this.http.get('urlService').pipe(
  switchMap((ids: number[]) => forkJoin(ids.slice(0, 20).map(id => this.getItems(id))))
).subscribe(newsList => {
  // newsList[0] - response from `this.getItems(1)`
  // newsList[1] - response from `this.getItems(2)`
  ...
  this.dataRecieved.next(newsList);
});
```

I am using Array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to convert the list `[1, 2, ..., 20]` to a list of HTTP requests `[this.getItems(1), this.getItems(2), ..., this.getItems(20)]`.

---

However, beware that this will trigger 20 simultaneous HTTP calls. Most browsers have a hard limit (Chrome - 6) on how many concurrent calls to the same domain could be made. The recommended way to solve this limit issue is to use WebSockets or domain sharding.

As a workaround from front-end, you could use RxJS [`bufferCount`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/bufferCount) operator with [`from`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from) function to control the maximum number of parallel requests made at a time.

```js
this.http.get('urlService').pipe(
  switchMap((ids: number[]) => from(ids.slice(0, 20).map(id => this.getItems(id)))),
  bufferCount(6),                         // <-- adjust number of parallel requests here
  concatMap(buffer => forkJoin(buffer))
).subscribe(
  newsList => this.dataRecieved.next(newsList),
  error => // handle error
);
```